# keras model import in Celery task

Tags: tensorflow, keras, celery

I am trying to import a keras model using tensorflow backend in celery, but the model won't load, and nothing happens. Ｉread on other posts and tried to put import in the task function, but this still doesn't help.

The code looks something like this:

```
@celery.task
def predict():
    from keras.models import load_model
    model = load_model(filepath)
    result = model.predict(data)
    return result
```

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? I'm trying to do the same thing. Any suggestion?

Comment: yes. It turned out I load the model in another  module, and somehow loading the model twice makes something wrong